# Loading Bootstrap before Jquery UI in ASP.Net MVC 4/Hot Towel template

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, requirejs, single-page-application

I am using MVC 4, Hot Towel templating and jQuery UI dialog. 
The thing is that there [is an issue](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/6887) between Bootstrap and jQuery UI that should be solved by loading Bootstrap before jQuery UI scripts.

The question is, how can I do that? I tried changing the `RegisterBundles` method, but sadly when I view HTML source code I can still see jQuery UI loaded before Bootstrap. I suppose that is because RequireJS is calling jQuery UI first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify dependencies in the [configuration](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config). I don't know anything about MVC4, but to me it looks like the `App/main.js` is the right file:

```
require.config({
    paths: { "text": "durandal/amd/text" }
    shim: {
        "jqueryui": {
            "deps": ["bootstrap"]
        }
    }
});
```